# Php SimpleXMLElement Utf-16

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, simplexml, utf-16

I want to create a `SimpleXMLElement object` via this line of code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Data/>');
```

Notice the encoding tag says `UTF-16`. Therefore the error `Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content` occurs.

So I tried it this way:

```
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><Data/>';
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-16,UTF-8')); //string(5) "UTF-8"
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-16,UTF-8')); //string(5) "UTF-8"

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string); //same error
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string); //same error
```

My understanding of string/character-encodings is not that good, perhaps I am missing something obvious?

Comment: Did you assign the return value from `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');` back to a `$var`. Before you call `mb_detect_encoding`

Comment: thanks, that was the problem! no error thrown now. but nevertheless `var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-16,UTF-8'));` returns `string(5) "UTF-8"` ..